# Removing spaces from specific column in CSV file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file with lines like this:

> 300001;Company Name;023-1 2 3 4 5 6 7;023-3 2 4 6 43
>   4;email@test.com;;;;Street Name;184;;Postal Code;City

I want to strip the spaces from column 3 and 4 (phone and fax number)so that it looks like this:

> 300001;Company Name;023-1234567;023-3246434;email@test.com;;;;Street
>   Name;184;;Postal Code;City

I tried these awk-codes (for column 3) I found on Stackoverflow with no luck:

```
awk -v FS=OFS=";" '{gsub(/ /,"",$3)} 1' file.csv > test.csv
awk -F, '$3 ~ / / { OFS= ";"; $3 = ""; } 1' file.csv > test.csv
```

I've been googling for half a day now, but can't find anything that works.

Comment: Can you expand the "with no luck" sentence? What was your output?

Comment: by no luck I mean that the output was the same as the input. But A.M.D.'s answer seems to have solved my problem!

Comment: Well the problem lies in the `-v FS=OFS=";"` expression, the `gsub()` part is fine. You cannot set two variables in the same expression, so you needed `-v FS=";" -v OFS=";"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(/ /,"",$3); gsub(/ /,"",$4)}1' File
```

We set the input and output field seperators as `;`. Then substitute the spaces in the `3rd` and `4th` fields with `nothing`. Hope it helps.

As others have already mentioned, setting both FS and OFS at one shot (`FS=OFS=";"`) with `-v` is the reason why it didn't work in your case. I moved the same to `BEGIN` block. Thats it.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Your answer seems to work, I'm gonna test it now on some files. Thanks!

Comment: i'll wait for your results :-)

Comment: Aaaaand..... the results are in! It works like a charm. Although the other solutions metioned in this thread also work, I'll mark yours as you're the first ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot set `FS` and `OFS` in one go. Seperate the two as

```
$ awk  -vFS=";" -vOFS=";" '{gsub(" ","",$3); gsub(" ", "", $4) }1' input
300001;Company Name;023-1234567;023-3246434;email@test.com;;;;Street Name;184;;Postal Code;City
```

Answer (score 1):

your cause of problem is `-v FS=OFS=";"` you can either use:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '...'
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} ...'
```

Other codes look ok, except that you forgot the column4. this line should work:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=";" 'gsub(/ /,"",$3)+gsub(/ /,"",$4)+7' file
```

Comment: `'gsub(/ /,"",$3)+gsub(/ /,"",$4)+7'` is one character briefer than `'{gsub(/ /,"",$3);gsub(/ /,"",$4)}7'`. Not sure it's worth the tradeoff in clarity or the time it took me thinking about it to convince myself it'd always succeed!